# Element.appendChild() hosed in IE .. workaround? (related to innerText vs textContent)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've heard that using `el.innerText||el.textContent` can yield unreliable cross-browswer results, so I'm walking the DOM tree to collect text nodes recursively, and write them into  tags in the HTML body.

What this script does is **read hash substring valus from the window.location and write them into the HTML**.

This script is working for me in Chrome & Firefox, but **choking in IE**.

I call the page with an URL syntax like this:

```
http://example.com/pagename.html#dyntext=FOO&dynterm=BAR&dynimage=FRED
```

---

**UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE**

**Solution:**

I moved the scripts to before `</body>` (where they should have been) then removed `console.log(sPageURL);` and now it's **working in Chrome, Firefox, IE8 and IE9**.

This my workaround for the innerText vs textContent crossbrowser issue when you are just placing text rather than getting text. In this case, getting hash substring values from the window.location and writing them into the page.

```
<html>
<body>

<span id="dyntext-span" style="font-weight: bold;"></span><br />
<span id="dynterm-span" style="font-style: italic;"></span><br />
<span id="dynimage-span" style="text-decoration: underline;"></span><br />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        var tags = ["dyntext", "dynterm", "dynimage"];
        for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; ++i) {
            var param = GetURLParameter(tags[i]);
            if (param) {
                var dyntext = GetURLParameter('dyntext');
                var dynterm = GetURLParameter('dynterm');
                var dynimage = GetURLParameter('dynimage');
            }
        }

        var elem = document.getElementById("dyntext-span");
        var text = document.createTextNode(dyntext);
        elem.appendChild(text);
        var elem = document.getElementById("dynterm-span");
        var text = document.createTextNode(dynterm);
        elem.appendChild(text);
        var elem = document.getElementById("dynimage-span");
        var text = document.createTextNode(dynimage);
        elem.appendChild(text);     
});

function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**FINAL UPDATE**

If your hash substring values **require spaces** (like a linguistic phrase with three words, for example) then separate the words with the `+` character in your URI, and replace the unicode `\u002B` character with a space when you create each text node, like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("dyntext-span");
var text = document.createTextNode(dyntext.replace(/\u002B/g, " "));
elem.appendChild(text);
var elem = document.getElementById("dynterm-span");
var text = document.createTextNode(dynterm.replace(/\u002B/g, " "));
elem.appendChild(text);
var elem = document.getElementById("dynimage-span");
var text = document.createTextNode(dynimage.replace(/\u002B/g, " "));
elem.appendChild(text);
```

Now form your URI like this:

```
http://example.com/pagename.html#dyntext=FOO+MAN+CHU&dynterm=BAR+HOPPING&dynimage=FRED+IS+DEAD
```

Comment: Could you be more specific with "choking on IE"? What version of IE? Any error in IE's Dev Tools (F12)? Also, a [known issue](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12282) in jQuery 1.8 is that it may fire the DOM Ready handler too early in IE9/10. Either move your scripts to the very end of the `<body>` tag (where they should be) or upgrade to jQuery 1.8.1, or do both (which is more appropriate).

Comment: You need to list each and every problem you are having with IE, because appendChild works perfectly in IE at least all the way back to IE6.  Adding jQuery and an unnecessarily complicated work around is not going to help us understand what you are doing wrong originally.

Comment: Forget my prior comment.  The bug you linked to is only in reference to a "style" tag, so this entire work around is invalid and unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When having `console.log()` in the code, you must have Dev Tools opened in IE. Also missing `head` element may cause some problems. Or is it missing only in this post?

Comment: Thanks @fabricio-matte and @Teemu ... Moved the scripts before `</body>` then removed `console.log(sPageURL);` and now it's working in IE8 and IE9. Thanks everybody. I could not have figured this out without your help.